# My Python VSC does not recognise Ursina - everything regarding that engine is underlined with yellow

Tags: python, ursina

I have tried importing ursina through cmd multiple times, updated pip, added newest python directories to path.

Ursina does not want to work, still.

I have tried the help that existing posts on here provided, but no solutions worked.

I installed ursina through cmd, and expected that when I did this:

from ursina import *

in the beginning of my code, it would import. It did not.

Answer (score 0):

(check just in case) If `from ursina import *` is the only line being caught, it's probably your linter complaining about code efficiency and security. I haven't had these problems neither on my Windows PC nor my MacBook Pro (pyenv).

If not, try these:

**1. Make sure `ursina` is installed to the virtualenv (or Python environment) you are trying to run it in.** Use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` to pull up the command bar in VSCode, then press enter on `Python: Select Interpreter` and make sure the correct environment is selected.

**2. Make sure you're not running `pip` or `python` with administrator privileges.** This is the same with `sudo` on `*nix` devices working with `python`, as `ursina` could be installed to the Administrator account, or `root` as a Linux example.

**3. Make sure `ursina` is actually installed through `pip freeze`.** In some cases, `pip` may glich and not actually install packages correctly. Try running the command `pip freeze` and search for `ursina==VERSION`. If it is not there, you should try reinstalling Python (with `pip`). If that does not work, try downloading someone's copy of their `ursina` folder in their `site-packages` directory to install `ursina` without `pip`.

**4. Try upgrading `pip`.** If there was a network issue, PyPI servers may have encountered an issue with `ursina` or other packages, and thus may have redirected clients to install wrong packages or even none at all. Run the following command to upgrade your `pip` version: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, or in recent Python versions, `pip install --upgrade pip`.

**5. Try creating a `virtualenv`, or `venv`.** Some packages might argue with the `ursina` version you're trying to install, and thus may make a collision occur. Creating an isolated Python environment for each of your Python projects can save you from errors like these. I advise you create a new virtual environment through `python -m venv`, activate the venv, then installing `ursina` to a fresh, clean environment dedicated for your `ursina` project.

**6. If none works, try reinstalling Python and `pip` completely.** Save your global packages through `pip freeze` and save it to a file on your desktop (or anywhere you want), and reinstall Python and `pip` from the [official python website](http://python.org). Your venvs will stay intact, only your global packages will be reset, or in other words, your `site-packages` folder. After reinsalling, with the `pip freeze` output, reinstall a few of your packages at a time to check whether `ursina` works or not. It is best to use virtualenvs for all your projects, so you can either take the time to split up your Python environments, or simply combine all for simplicity.

If you tried all of these, or have difficulties/errors while doing them, leave a comment and I'll try to see what's going on.

Quick Edit: You could also try reinstalling your Python-related VSC extensions, including IntelliSense, maybe that could refresh their package lists.